# Find $E[(x+2)^2]$ Given $E[x]$

Tags: expected-value

Find
$
E[(x+2)^2]
$
given that $
E[x] = 5, Var(X) = 2
$.

I'm not sure if I'm making this more complicated than it should be. However, this is what I did.

$$
E[(x+2)^2] = 
E[x^2+2x+4] = 
E[x^2]+E[2x]+4 = E[x^2]+2E[x]+4 = 25+10+4 = 39.
$$
I'm unsure is if $E[x^2]$ is 25. And furthermore, if there's an easier method to solving this problem if $x+2$ was raised to a higher power

Comment: the expected value of $x^2$ is completely unknown; everything else you did was ok. Do you know the variance?

Comment: Made the edit, forgot to mention variance was 5, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other information, it is not possible to compute the desired expectation.  This is because $\operatorname{E}[X] = 5$ does not uniquely determine $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$.  In fact, if $\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[(X+2)^2] 
&= \operatorname{E}[(X - \mu + \mu + 2)^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(X - \mu)^2 + 2(\mu + 2)(X - \mu) + (\mu + 2)^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(X - \mu)^2] + 2(\mu + 2)\operatorname{E}[X - \mu] + (\mu+2)^2 \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X] + 2(\mu + 2)(\mu - \mu) + (\mu + 2)^2 \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X] + (\mu + 2)^2.
\end{align}$$

This shows that the desired expectation equals the variance plus $(\mu + 2)^2 = 49$.  So for instance, if $X$ is normally distributed with mean $5$, we can pick *any* nonnegative variance we please.  All that we can say is that $\operatorname{E}[(X+2)^2] \ge 49$.

Answer (score 0):

> Find $E[(x+2)^2]$ given that $E[x]=5$ ,$Var(X)=2$.

@Jones, observe that:

- When you refer to rv you have to use always a Capital letter
- your binomial expansion is wrong.
- In the post you stated $\mathbb{V}(X)=2$, in your comment you stated it as 5. I assume correct what you stated in your post as it is the more recent edit.
- remember that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{V}(X)+\mathbb{E}^2(X)=2+5^2=27$

Given this, you get

$$\mathbb{E}[(X+2)^2]=\mathbb{E}(X^2)+4\mathbb{E}(X)+4=27+4\times 5+4=51$$

Answer (score 0):

No, $\displaystyle E\left[ X^{2}\right] \neq 25$.

But, you can probabily recal that: $\displaystyle Var( X) =E\left[ X^{2}\right] -( E[ X])^{2}$.

---

From here:

$\displaystyle E\left[ X^{2}\right] =Var( X) +( E[ X])^{2} =2+25=27$.

Now,

$\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
E\left[( X+2)^{2}\right] =E\left[ x^{2} +4X+4\right] =E\left[ X^{2}\right] +E[ 4X] +E[ 4] =E\left[ X^{2}\right] +4E[ X] +4\\
=27+4\cdotp 5+4=51
\end{array}$